# Переносимость проекта (зависимости) на C++

Tags: c++, library, зависимости

Добрый день имеется проект написанный на C++ из библиотек используется CppCMS, SOCI, Boost в данный момент все это дело собирается CMake c помощью компилятора CLang. Проблема заключается в том, что если возникает необходимость собрать проект на другой машине (а она возникает) то на ней нет библиотек, от которых зависит проект, вопрос в том, имеется ли какой-то способ автоматизировать выкачку и сборку библиотек что бы скачав проект с гита можно было продолжить работу над ним без установки всех библиотек вручную,пробовал Conan но во-первых в нем нет всех необходимых библиотек, во-вторых даже Boost который есть в нем не собирается.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8153519/13970074

Comment: Какая ОС? Или вы хотите кросс-платформенно?

Comment: В `CMake` есть `ExternalProject` (качает во время билда) и `FetchContent` (качает во время конфигурации).